# ASUS laptop WON'T stay OFF

Tags: laptop, asus

Plesae help. My ASUS laptop (gl502vm) wont stay off, after fully shut down unexpectedly starts. I try turn off "restart after crash", "fast startup", make new power plan and others tips from internet but nothing helps.

Comment: Get into BIOS and look for and turn OFF any “Wake On” setting. There may be more than one, but Wake On LAN is common. Check them all.

Comment: Try running "shutdown /s /f /t 00" in Run box or CMD. See https://www.howtogeek.com/512012/how-to-shut-down-your-windows-10-pc-using-command-prompt/ . Also, try holding power button for 5 seconds to force shutdown.